# GCC Output file error

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, g++, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using visual studio code with ubuntu 16.04 LTS compiling with gcc version 5.5. Whenever I try to build the program in visual studio code using ctrl+shift+b, I get the error shown in the screenshot, the only reference I can find is in the tasks.json file, but I'll also include the c_cpp_properties file too in case that helps, simply put, I'm not exactly sure what is causing the output file to say no such file or directory, I thought it was supposed to create the output file or do I have to do it in advance? It also references a usr/bin/ld directory which doesn't seem to exist on my filesystem which is odd. Any and all help would be appreciated, if more information is needed, feel free to ask.

[image: Error output]

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "opt/opencv/release/include",
            "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/nlohmann_json/3.1.2/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build app",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g", "src/calibration.cpp",
            "-o", "build/calibration.out",
            "-I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/nlohmann_json/3.1.2/include",
            "-std=c++11",
            "-L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib",
            "-lopencv_stitching",
            "-lopencv_superres",
            "-lopencv_videostab",
            "-lopencv_aruco",
            "-lopencv_bgsegm",
            "-lopencv_bioinspired",
            "-lopencv_ccalib",
            "-lopencv_dnn_objdetect",
            "-lopencv_dpm",
            "-lopencv_face",
            "-lopencv_photo",
            "-lopencv_fuzzy",
            "-lopencv_hfs",
            "-lopencv_img_hash",
            "-lopencv_line_descriptor",
            "-lopencv_optflow",
            "-lopencv_reg",
            "-lopencv_rgbd",
            "-lopencv_saliency",
            "-lopencv_stereo",
            "-lopencv_structured_light",
            "-lopencv_phase_unwrapping",
            "-lopencv_surface_matching",
            "-lopencv_tracking",
            "-lopencv_datasets",
            "-lopencv_dnn",
            "-lopencv_plot",
            "-lopencv_xfeatures2d",
            "-lopencv_shape",
            "-lopencv_video",
            "-lopencv_ml",
            "-lopencv_ximgproc",
            "-lopencv_calib3d",
            "-lopencv_features2d",
            "-lopencv_highgui",
            "-lopencv_videoio",
            "-lopencv_flann",
            "-lopencv_xobjdetect",
            "-lopencv_imgcodecs",
            "-lopencv_objdetect",
            "-lopencv_xphoto",
            "-lopencv_imgproc",
            "-lopencv_core"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Try creating the output directory "build" manually.

Comment: That worked, but I marked the person who answered first as correct since they explained it to me a bit more too, thanks for your contribution though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/ld` is gcc linker. From the error you shown the problem is not that `/usr/bin/ld` doesn't exists but that the directory `build` in which you want to create the executable `calibration.out` does not exist.

Go to your workspace directory and run `mkdir build` or create the folder using the GUI.

Comment: Is the work space the src directory where the actual code is, or would it be in .vscode where the c_cpp_properties.json and tasks.json are? Just want to be super clear so I know for the future too, thanks. Sorry, was not quite getting it there for a second.

Comment: `calibration.out` is the name of the executable file. `build` is the name of the directory.  It is written in your json file `"-o", "build/calibration.out",`.The workspace folder is the root that vscode use in your project.

Answer (score 1):

building files by invoking gcc directly will just about work for a single file but you will run into issues like this one.

I'd recommend you look into a proper build system, there are many to choose from including:

- Make - the main standard build system on Linux but difficult to learn and fiddly
- CMake - visual studio code has some support for cmake
- Gyp - can generate make files
- Scons - python like build scripts

The issue you are having is that nothing is creating your `build` directory. You need to create it yourself before running your build task.